# Necessary to have a comments.php if there are no comments?

Tags: comments

For a totally-custom WP site, is it necessary to have the theme-required pages like comments.php and single.php (which would be blank files in the folder) if they are either not used or overridden by other pages just so that WP doesn't potentially act buggy?

Comment: No, they are not required. Just make sure no other theme files (which are being executed) are using them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum Template Files for Theme Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84064/minimum-template-files-for-theme-development)